# Using Wordpress plugins_url function gives 403 forbidden error

Tags: php, wordpress, file-get-contents

I am writing a plugin and am trying to get the contents of a text file. This is working:

```
$ipn_log = WP_PLUGIN_DIR."/plugin-folder/filename.txt"; 
$log_contents = file_get_contents($ipn_log);
```

However, Wordpress Codex says plugins should not use `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`, but use the `plugins_url` function instead: http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories

So, I try doing this:

```
$ipn_log = plugins_url( 'filename.txt', __FILE__ );
$log_contents = file_get_contents($ipn_log);
```

When I use `plugins_url`, I get a 403 forbidden error. Any idea why? Should I not be using `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server may not [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) or you may not have the URL properly encoded. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: allow_url_fopen is enabled as I can get contents of files by other means (see my question). If I echo the URL either using WP_PLUGIN_DIR or plugins_url, it is exactly the same.

Comment: By using `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` you are getting the file by path not by url like when using `plugins_url()`.  I still think the permissions problems are from using a URL.

Comment: Try using `plugin_dir_path` instead of `plugins_url`.